# Why can I sell certain expensive vehicles but not others?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I sold the JB 700 for 173k and the Comet for another 74k.  When I try to sell others, it's giving me the message that I can't sell vehicles over 50k. Thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has to do with a certain patch within the game. This problem often occurs if you bought the car before one of the earlier patches. You could try clearing the cache data on your console and making sure that you are updated to the latest patch.